# Grails - restful-api plugin matches url, but returns 404

Tags: rest, grails, grails-plugin, restful-url

I am trying to create a restful api using [RESTful API](https://github.com/restfulapi/restful-api) plugin for Grails.  I am trying to hit `http://localhost:8080/grails-api/qapi/searchs?query=abc`, but I am getting a 404 returned.  What is going on here?

### Log

```
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [500]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/qapi/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Matched URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/qapi/(*)], adding to posibilities
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/api/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/api/(*)/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/api/(*)/(*)/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Matched URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?], adding to posibilities
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/dbdoc/(*)?/(*)?/(*)?/(*)?]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/api/(*)/(*)/(*)/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/assets/(**)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [500]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/qapi/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Matched URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/qapi/(*)], adding to posibilities
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/api/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/api/(*)/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/api/(*)/(*)/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Matched URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?], adding to posibilities
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/dbdoc/(*)?/(*)?/(*)?/(*)?]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/api/(*)/(*)/(*)/(*)]
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Attempting to match URI [/qapi/searchs] with pattern [/assets/(**)]
DEBUG filter.UrlMappingsFilter  - No match found, processing remaining filter chain
```

### UrlMappings.groovy

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
    constraints {
        // apply constraints here
    }
}

// Default controller to handle RESTful API requests.
// Place URL mappings to specific controllers BEFORE this mapping.
//
"/api/$pluralizedResourceName/$id"(controller:'restfulApi') {
    action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update",
              DELETE: "delete"]
    parseRequest = false
    constraints {
        // to constrain the id to numeric, uncomment the following:
        // id matches: /\d+/
    }
}
"/api/$pluralizedResourceName"(controller:'restfulApi') {
    action = [GET: "list", POST: "create"]
    parseRequest = false
}

// Support for nested resources. You may add additional URL mappings to handle
// additional nested resource requirements.
//
"/api/$parentPluralizedResourceName/$parentId/$pluralizedResourceName/$id"(controller:'restfulApi') {
    action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", DELETE: "delete"]
    parseRequest = false
    constraints {
        // to constrain the id to numeric, uncomment the following:
        // id matches: /\d+/
    }
}

"/api/$parentPluralizedResourceName/$parentId/$pluralizedResourceName"(controller:'restfulApi') {
    action = [GET: "list", POST: "create"]
    parseRequest = false
}

"/qapi/$pluralizedResourceName"(controller:'restfulApi') {
    action = [GET: "list", POST: "search"]
    parseRequest = false
}

"/"(view:"/index")
"500"(view:'/error')
```

Comment: I've never used this plugin so this is probably a shot in the dark, but are you missing the proper gsp template to render the instances? Does it work if you change the response format to e.g. JSON (by including `format=json`)?

Comment: @GregorPetrin, yeah this plugin does not render a view to the client, it is a REST plugin.

Comment: Ok, my bad, the default Grails' REST implementation can render responses to HTML, JSON or XML and I've had 404s this way. Sorry for the noise!

Comment: @GregorPetrin, yeah man been through that as well.  Thanks though.